# Is it possible to set CPUAffinity=0 for a specific process in its systemd service unit file?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-service

Is it possible to set CPUAffinity=0 for a specific process (lets say httpd.service) in its systemd service unit file?

Answer (score 0):

The default CPU affinity mask `CPUAffinity=0,24,48,72` applies to all services managed by systemd, but you can set your own affinity settings per unit.

To set a CPU affinity mask for a systemd service, use the `CPUAffinity` unit file option:

1. Check the values of the CPUAffinity unit file option in the service of your choice:

`$ systemctl show --property CPUAffinity <service name>`

2. As root, set the required value as the affinity mask (like "0"):

`systemctl set-property <service name> CPUAffinity=0`

3. Restart the service

`systemctl restart <service name>`